# How can I Return a Value from 1st Function after calling it in 2nd function in another js file using callback with multiple parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, callback

Suppose,

### first.js file:

```
function get(p1,p2){
    var fruits = [p1,p2]
    if(fruits.includes('banana')){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

### second.js file:

```
function getfruit(){
     const val = get("banana","mango")
     return val
}
```

As you people know, javascript is asynchronous in nature so Here I want 1st function which is get function should execute 1st and return the value of it then only it should return that value in the 2nd function, which is getfruit function.

Note: Parameters should not be less than 2 in function.

Thanks in advance if you can provide any solution for it.

Comment: Yes, there is `async` and `await`, but that doesn't make JavaScript "asynchronous" in nature; JavaScript is actually quite the opposite - in web browsers at least - it runs single threaded i.e. synchronously

Comment: Have a look here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax  You should then get -> `const get = (...fruits) => [...fruits].includes('banana')`

Comment: "*As you people know, javascript is asynchronous in nature*" - no, it is not. Your functions are synchronous, all the statements within them are executed in sequence. You do not need callbacks, promises, `async`/`await` or anything.

Comment: What is actually going wrong? The code you provided will work as intended when at least you have some code that *calls* `getFruit` and does something useful with the boolean value it gets back.